# Button click in repeater in updatepanel not triggered until AsyncPostBackTrigger timer tick?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a bit of a strange problem and wondering if anyone can help.

I have an update panel that has a timer set as the AsyncPostBackTrigger.
In this Update Panel I have a repeater and in the repeater I have a few buttons which have on click events.

The on click of these buttons does not *appear* to fire until the timer has ticked.
I have tried debugging and this is what seems to be happening, either way it takes ages for the button click to actually fire.

Does anyone know why this would be and what I can do about it?

My code is as follows:

Update Panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="CheckListUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <div><asp:Label ID="CannotBeLoadedLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></div>
        <table>
            <asp:Repeater ID="ChecklistRepeater" runat="server">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Description")%>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Priority")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="SetAsCompleteButton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("EventChecklistId")%>'
                                runat="server" OnClick="SetAsCompleteButton_Click" Text="Close" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
 </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Some of my code behind:

```
  Protected Sub SetAsCompleteButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        timer1.Enabled = False

~~do complete code    

        timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

 Protected Sub timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles timer1.Tick
        timer1.Enabled = False
        LoadEventChecklist()
        timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Thanks

Bex

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# Eval("EventChecklistId")%>
```

This could be the reason. What is the value inside ? It could require full postback to evaluate.

Comment: This is an ID value bound from the data source to the repeater. The button needs this value when it posts back to know what item it is setting to complete. Is there a way round that?

Comment: Can't you pass ClientID, which is already there
<%=DataSourceControl.ClientID%>

Comment: What do you mean? Pass the entire datasource to the code? I am binding this from the code behind too, s I'm not using a datasource control if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You should use itemCommand event of the Repeater to capture the button click, something like

```
    protected void ChecklistRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.CommandArgument // This will give the argument specified in the button
        //Your Code
}
```

and you can get the event argument as e.CommandArgument inside this method to process accordingly.

Comment: thanks for that! its something else that was causing it to appear as if it was waiting for the timer tick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something else was causing the button to appear as if it was not being fired until the timer click.
So none of the other answers were a problem, although useful to know for future..
I am marking this as answer to close the question..

Feel free to delete

Comment: "It was something else" is literally the most unhelpful response you can possibly give to your own forum post.